Office.js Excel Startup Function
I have a custom function file (functions.js), which is used to define the functions, but also at the end of the file, I call the following code
Office.initialize = async function () {
  console.log("Starting up");
  await startup();
  console.log("Finished starting up");
};

This does not always run when the document loads - even though part of the 'startup' method sets
Office.addin.setStartupBehavior(Office.StartupBehavior.load);
If I load the task pane associated with the function, it all runs, but if I dont open the task pane, it seems to be hit or miss whether it loads.
Is there way to ensure that this code loads every time, even if the task pane is not opened?
All of this is running on Excel on the Web - hence the console.log messages.
Any ideas?

The fact that startup is async makes me wonder if it sometimes completes in time and sometimes doesn't. Is there a reason why it is async?

Only because some of the calls under it are async. But the console log messages don’t even appear!
